Has any eventual last-place team beaten the eventual champions twice in a home-and-away competition?
Wolverhampton Wanderers won the 2017–18 EFL Championship, beating all teams at least once except last-placed Sunderland, against whom they had a 0-0 draw and a 0-3 loss.
Has any eventual last-place team beaten the eventual champions twice in a home-and-away competition? I have managed to find some similar situations, but all were from continental championships.
The teams must have finished top and bottom of the table by playing alone; positions due to penalties imposed by the organisers do not count.

In the 1954-55 French top flight, Stade De Reims were beaten by eventual last placed team CO Roubaix-Tourcoing both times:
Roubaix-Tourc 2-1 Reims
Roubaix-Tourc 2-0 Reims

this is my 2nd account

I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?

We appreciate the explicit acknowledgement of the secondary account, as it supports our good faith assumption, but please beware of allowing any such accounts to interact, particularly through any form of voting. If you would like to keep a single account, you will need to register it, which includes providing an email address that you can legitimately access. Outside of this, unregistered accounts are managed using cookies, which are up to an individual's own device and software to maintain, and are unlikely be verifiable (and will be at risk of removal at any time).

TLDR; No.
I have done some searching of the database I have built partly from flashscores and a few other sites. My data for English leagues goes back to the following season:

Prem 92/93
Cham 92/93
L1 92/93
L2 92/93
Conf 92/93
Conf N 04/05
Conf S 04/05

All are missing the covid seasons of 19/20 and 20/21.
Firstly no bottom team has beaten the top team home and away, I was a bit suprised at this, I have queried 186 leagues, you'd have thought that one bottom team would have done it once.
The list below is bottom teams that were undefeated against the top team:
L1      Southend    0-0 Walsall     2006-02-25  -   Walsall     2-2 Southend    2005-08-13
Conf S  Braintree   1-1 St. Albans  2011-03-19  -   St. Albans  0-0 Braintree   2010-08-21
Cham    Burnley     3-3 Blackpool*  2022-08-20  -   Blackpool*  0-0 Burnley     2023-03-04
Conf    Kidderm     0-0 Witton A    1993-11-20  -   Witton A    2-0 Kidderm     1993-09-14
L2      Brentford   1-1 Scarborough 1999-02-27  -   Scarborough 3-1 Brentford   1998-09-19
Cham    Man City    2-2 Stockport C 2001-10-13  -   Stockport C 2-1 Man City    2002-03-19
Cham    Wolves      0-0 Sunderland  2017-12-09  -   Sunderland  3-0 Wolves      2018-05-06

*Blackpool technically finished 23rd that season with Wigan given a penalty.
Out of curiosity I did a query for what lowest league position has done the double over the Champions and second-from-bottom has done it once:
Conf S  Eastleigh   1-2 Tonbridge   2013-11-23  -   Tonbridge   2-1 Eastleigh   2014-02-17

And the bottom team has beaten second-from-top home and away once as well:
L2      Bury        0-1 Stockport C 2010-11-13  -   Stockport C 2-1 Bury        2011-02-12

